# How to get Thread Id from the exception pointer in the VectorExceptionHandler?

Tags: c++, seh

I want to get the thread Id of the thread where SEH exception occurred. I currently have the Handler installed in Main, so need the thread Id where the exception happened.

```
LONG WINAPI VehHandler(PEXCEPTION_POINTERS exceptionInfo)
{
    if(GetCurrentThreadId() == Thread where exception happened){
        //Do Something
    }
}
```